# <a></a> tags not being rendered when put in quotes

Tags: python, html, django, google-app-engine

I know that this is a trivial error but I am not being able to debug it.
When I put  tags in quotes and dynamically generate a string for a link, the 'link' is not generated. Rather the '<', '>' are being rendered as they are. (I am trying to run a python script in GAE which uses django templating framework)

Following is my code:

```
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template  

...  

html = html + template.render('templates/footer.html',
                                          {'links': 'Enter <a href="/">another sighting</a>.'})
```

The following is the 'footer.html' in templates:

```
<p>
{{ links }}
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And following is the output:

[image: Output on browser]

Any help would be appreciated. (This is the situation in both Firefox and Google Chrome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `safe` filter to your variable:

```
{{ links|safe }}
```

Or mark your string as safe in the python code using [`mark_safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe) function:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

html = html + template.render('templates/footer.html',
            {'links': mark_safe('Enter <a href="/">another sighting</a>.')})
```

This is the django's [automatic HTML escaping](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/#automatic-html-escaping) mechanism. You can control it with [autoescape](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape) template tag but I don't recommend to do it :-)

Comment: Thanks! It worked! But why did not it work the first time, i.e., the way I had written it? (I was actually referring a tutorial on the same and it worked on that, although it was using a GAE tutorial for python 2.5 and mine is 2.7)

Comment: This is the one of the coolest django's features. Read the documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/#automatic-html-escaping